# Cannot execute auto-generated Python script encoded in UTF8-sig

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am using a Python script to take some text from the internet and put it as comments to another Python script which the first one generates.
Originally I was simply using `open()` to open create the new Python script and `write()` to print to it.

```
outputFile = open(fileName, 'w')
outputFile.write('#!/usr/bin/python\n')
outputFile.write('\n')
outputFile.write('# ' + lineFromTheInternet + '\n')
outputFile.write('print \'Hello, World!\'\n')
```

This works most of the time, the new script is generated and I can run it. However, sometimes the text that I am taking from the internet has Unicode characters and gives me problems (`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)`). I replaced the code then to:

```
outputFile = codecs.open(fileName, 'w', 'utf-8-sig)
outputFile.write('#!/usr/bin/python\n')
outputFile.write('\n')
outputFile.write('# ' + lineFromTheInternet + '\n')
outputFile.write('print \'Hello, World!\'\n')
```

And this would generate the file correctly, but when I try to execute it I get `./autogenerated.py: line 1: ﻿#!/usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`

This has to be the encoding, since it's the only thing changing, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: You don't get the error using python3, maybe this would be an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux or Windows?  This works on Windows.  Make sure to write Unicode strings to the file opened with `codecs.open`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import codecs
with codecs.open('y.py', 'w', 'utf-8-sig') as outputFile:
    outputFile.write(u'#!/usr/bin/python2\n')
    outputFile.write(u'\n')
    outputFile.write(u'# ' + u'Syst\xe9m' + u'\n')
    outputFile.write(u'print \'Hello, World!\'\n')
```

AFAIK, Linux may not like the UTF-8 BOM.  Try removing it and declaring the encoding instead, e.g. `#coding:utf8` at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import codecs
with codecs.open('y.py', 'w', 'utf8') as outputFile:
    outputFile.write(u'#!/usr/bin/python2\n')
    outputFile.write(u'#coding:utf8\n')
    outputFile.write(u'\n')
    outputFile.write(u'# ' + u'Syst\xe9m' + u'\n')
    outputFile.write(u'print \'Hello, World!\'\n')
```

Comment: Linux. I'll try writing Unicode strings then and let you know, thanks!